# Why are there two player speeds in my game?

Tags: java, user-interface

For some reason there are two player speeds in my game Orange Quest. What I mean by this is when I test my game in eclipse and my headphones are off. The game goes twice as fast as when my headphones are on.
I sent the game to my friend and he also experiences the same problems. I've tried to debug the code to see if there was a something wrong with it, but I didn't see any problem. I also tried to adjust the player speed but that didn't help either, as it was still going twice as fast when my headphones were off.
Here is the code for the game panel
Oh yah, by the way the frame is 700 by 700

```
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList;

public class GamePanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    Player player;

    boolean running = true;
    CopyOnWriteArrayList<Wall> walls = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();
    CopyOnWriteArrayList<LavaWall> lavaWalls = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();
    CopyOnWriteArrayList<Enemy> enemies = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();
    CopyOnWriteArrayList<Orange> oranges = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();

    java.util.Timer gameTimer;
    int cameraX;
    int offset;
    int count = 0;
    int index = 0;
    int set;
    int s = 50;
    int r = 75;
    BufferedImage dirt;
    BufferedImage grass;
    BufferedImage lava;
    BufferedImage cloud;
    BufferedImage spike;
    BufferedImage undergroundLava;
    BufferedImage character;
    BufferedImage thumbnail;
    JLabel timeLabel = new JLabel();
    JLabel orangeLabel = new JLabel(": 0/7");
    double orangeCount = 0;
    int elapsedTime = 0;
    int minutes = 0;
    int seconds = 0;
    int ms = 0;
    String minutesString = String.format("%02d", minutes);
    String secondsString = String.format("%02d", seconds);
    String msString = String.format("%02d", ms);
    java.util.Timer timer = new java.util.Timer();
    TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            elapsedTime += 10;
            minutes = (elapsedTime / 60000);
            seconds = (elapsedTime / 1000) % 60;
            ms = (elapsedTime / 10) % 100;
            minutesString = String.format("%02d", minutes);
            secondsString = String.format("%02d", seconds);
            msString = String.format("%02d", ms);
            timeLabel.setText(minutesString + ":" + secondsString + ":" + msString);
        }

    };

    GamePanel() {

        if (running) {
            player = new Player(400, 300, this);
            reset();
            setLayout(null);
            gameTimer = new java.util.Timer();
            add(player.death);
            player.death.setBounds(550, 15, 300, 100);
            player.death.setFont(new Font("Verdana", Font.PLAIN, 20));
            add(orangeLabel);
            orangeLabel.setBounds(320, 15, 200, 50);
            orangeLabel.setFont(new Font("Verdana", Font.PLAIN, 20));
            gameTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

                @Override
                public void run() {

                    try {
                        if (walls.get(walls.size() - 1).x < 800) {
                            offset += 700;
                            makeWalls(offset);
                        }

                        player.set();
                        for (Wall wall : walls)
                            wall.set(cameraX);
                        for (int i = 0; i < walls.size(); i++) {
                            if (walls.get(i).x < -800)
                                walls.remove(i);
                        }for(Enemy enemy : enemies)
                            enemy.set(cameraX);
                        for (LavaWall lava : lavaWalls)
                            lava.set(cameraX);
                        for (int i = 0; i < lavaWalls.size(); i++) {
                            if (lavaWalls.get(i).x < -800)
                                lavaWalls.remove(i);
                        }
                        for(Orange orange : oranges)
                            orange.set(cameraX);
                        for(int i = 0; i < oranges.size(); i++) {
                            if(oranges.get(i).x < -800)
                                oranges.remove(i);
                        }
                        repaint();

                    } catch (Throwable e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, 0, 17);
            add(timeLabel);
            timeLabel.setText(minutesString + ":" + secondsString + ":" + msString);
            timeLabel.setBounds(10, 15, 300, 100);
            timeLabel.setFont(new Font("Verdana", Font.PLAIN, 25));
            timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 0, 10);
        } else if (!running) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    public void makeWalls(int offset) {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        try {
            dirt = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/art/dirt block.png"));
            grass = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/art/grass block.png"));
            lava = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/art/lava block.png"));
            cloud = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/art/cloud block.png"));
            undergroundLava = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/art/underground lava.png"));
            thumbnail = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/art/thumbnail.png"));
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (count == 7) {
            oranges.add(new Orange(offset + 50, 500, s, s, thumbnail)); 
            for (int i = 1; i <= 14; i++) {
                walls.add(new Wall(offset + i * 50, 600, s, s, grass));
                walls.add(new Wall(offset + i * 50, 650, s, s, dirt));
            }

        }
        else if(count != 10) {
            if (index == 0) {
                for (int i = 1; i <= 14; i++) {
                    walls.add(new Wall(offset + i * 50, 600, s, s, grass));
                    walls.add(new Wall(offset + i * 50, 650, s, s, dirt));
                    if(i == 6) {
                        enemies.add(new Enemy(offset + 350, 550, r, s));
                    }
                }
                set = 0;
            } else if (index == 1) {
                for (int j = 1; j <= 14; j++) {
                    for (int i = 650; i >= 350; i -= 50) {
                        if (i == 350)
                            walls.add(new Wall(offset, i, s, s, grass));
                        else
                            walls.add(new Wall(offset, i, s, s, dirt));
                    }
                    offset += 50;
                    set = 1;
                }
            } else if (index == 2) {
                if(set == 0) {
                    walls.add(new Wall(offset - 50, 500, s, s, cloud));
                    walls.add(new Wall(offset - 200, 400, s, s, cloud));
                    walls.add(new Wall(offset, 300, s, s, cloud));

                    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
                        walls.add(new Wall(offset + 300 + i * 50, 600, s, s, grass));
                        walls.add(new Wall(offset + 300 + i * 50, 650, s, s, dirt));
                    }
                }else {
                    for (int i = 1; i <= 14; i++) {
                        walls.add(new Wall(offset + i * 50, 600, s, s, grass));
                        walls.add(new Wall(offset + i * 50, 650, s, s, dirt));
                        if(i == 6) {
                            enemies.add(new Enemy(offset + 350, 550, r, s));
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else if (index == 3) {
                for (int i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
                    walls.add(new Wall(offset + i * 50, 600, s, s, grass));
                    walls.add(new Wall(offset + i * 50, 650, s, s, dirt));
                }
                lavaWalls.add(new LavaWall(offset + 150, 600, s, s, lava));
                lavaWalls.add(new LavaWall(offset + 200, 600, s, s, lava));
                lavaWalls.add(new LavaWall(offset + 250, 600, s, s, lava));
                lavaWalls.add(new LavaWall(offset + 300, 600, s, s, lava));
                lavaWalls.add(new LavaWall(offset + 350, 600, s, s, lava));
                lavaWalls.add(new LavaWall(offset + 150, 650, s, s, undergroundLava));
                lavaWalls.add(new LavaWall(offset + 200, 650, s, s, undergroundLava));
                lavaWalls.add(new LavaWall(offset + 250, 650, s, s, undergroundLava));
                lavaWalls.add(new LavaWall(offset + 300, 650, s, s, undergroundLava));
                lavaWalls.add(new LavaWall(offset + 350, 650, s, s, undergroundLava));
                for (int i = 6; i <= 12; i++) {
                    walls.add(new Wall(offset + 100 + i * 50, 600, s, s, grass));
                    walls.add(new Wall(offset + 100 + i * 50, 650, s, s, dirt));
                }
            }
            for(Wall wall : walls) {
                for(LavaWall lava : lavaWalls) {
                    if(lava.hitBox.getBounds() == wall.hitBox.getBounds()) {
                        lavaWalls.remove(lava);
                    }
                }
            }
            count++;
            index = rnd.nextInt(4);
        }
    }

    public void reset() {
        count = 0;
        index = 0;
        player.x = 200;
        player.y = 150;

        cameraX = 150;
        player.xspeed = 0;
        player.yspeed = 0;
        walls.clear();
        enemies.clear();
        lavaWalls.clear();
        oranges.clear();
        offset = -150;
        makeWalls(offset);  
        player.isDed = false;
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {



        try {
            super.paint(g);
            Graphics2D gtd = (Graphics2D) g;
            player.draw(gtd);
            for(int i = 0; i < walls.size(); i++) {
                try {
                    walls.get(i).draw(gtd);
                } catch (Throwable e) {

                }
            }for(Enemy enemy : enemies) 
                enemy.draw(gtd);
            for(LavaWall lava : lavaWalls)
                lava.draw(gtd);
            g.drawImage(thumbnail, 270, 15, 50, 50, null);
            for(Orange orange : oranges)
                orange.draw(gtd);
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {



        if (e.getKeyChar() == 'a')
            player.keyLeft = true;
        if (e.getKeyChar() == 'w' || e.getKeyCode() == 32)
            player.keyUp = true;
        if (e.getKeyChar() == 's')
            player.keyDown = true;
        if (e.getKeyChar() == 'd')
            player.keyRight = true;
        if (e.getKeyChar() == 'h')
            Player.keyGlide = true;
        if (e.getKeyChar() == 'j')
            player.keyMega = true;
        if (e.getKeyChar() == 'l')
            player.keyRush = true;

    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {



        if (e.getKeyChar() == 'a')
            player.keyLeft = false;
        if (e.getKeyChar() == 'w' || e.getKeyCode() == 32)
            player.keyUp = false;
        if (e.getKeyChar() == 's')
            player.keyDown = false;
        if (e.getKeyChar() == 'd')
            player.keyRight = false;
        if (e.getKeyCode() == 27)
            System.exit(0);
        if (e.getKeyChar() == 'h')
            Player.keyGlide = false;
        if (e.getKeyChar() == 'j')
            player.keyMega = false;
        if (e.getKeyChar() == 'l')
            player.keyRush = false;
    }
}
```

and here is the player code

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;

import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;
import javax.swing.*;
public class Player {
    GamePanel panel;
    int x;
    int y;
    int width;
    int height;
    double xspeed;
    double yspeed;
    boolean keyLeft;
    boolean keyRight;
    boolean keyUp;
    static boolean keyGlide;
    boolean keyDown;
    boolean keyMega;
    boolean keyRush;
    boolean falling;
    boolean isDeathSound;
    boolean isDed;
    Graphics2D gtd;
    long time = 0;
    Timer timer;
    long start; 
    long stop;
    double deaths = 0;
    JLabel death = new JLabel("Deaths: 0");
    Rectangle hitBox;   
    long waitTime;
    static Clip clip;
    static boolean onGround;

    Player(){

    }
    Player(int x, int y, GamePanel panel){



        this.panel = panel;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        width = 50;
        height = 100;
        hitBox = new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);
    }
    public void set() throws Throwable{
        Iterator<Orange> orangeItr = panel.oranges.iterator();
        if(keyLeft && keyRight || !keyLeft && !keyRight) xspeed *= 0.8;
        else if(keyLeft && !keyRight)xspeed--; 
        else if(keyRight && !keyLeft)xspeed++;
        if(keyUp && keyGlide) {keyUp = false;}
        if(yspeed > 0)onGround = false;
        if(keyMega && keyGlide) {keyMega = false;}
        if(onGround && keyGlide)keyGlide = false;
        if(xspeed > 0 && xspeed < 0.75)xspeed = 0;
        if(xspeed < 0 && xspeed > -0.75)xspeed = 0;
        if(xspeed > 7 && !keyRush)xspeed = 7;
        if(xspeed < -7 && !keyRush)xspeed = -7;
        if(xspeed > 12 && keyRush)xspeed = 12;
        if(xspeed < -12 && keyRush)xspeed = -12;

        if(yspeed < -12.75) yspeed = -12.75;
        if(keyUp && onGround) {
            jumpSound();
            hitBox.y++;
            onGround = false;
            for(Wall wall : panel.walls) {

                if(wall.hitBox.intersects(hitBox)) {
                    yspeed = -8;

                }
            }hitBox.y--;
        }if(keyMega && onGround) {
            megaSound();
            onGround = false;
            hitBox.y++;

            for(Wall wall : panel.walls) {
                if(wall.hitBox.intersects(hitBox)) yspeed = -12.75;

            }hitBox.y--;

        }
        yspeed += 0.3;
        if(keyGlide && !onGround && yspeed > 1.2) {
            glideSound();
            yspeed -= 0.25;


        }if(keyDown && !onGround) {
            yspeed += 0.4;
        }
        //horizontal collision
        hitBox.x += xspeed;
        for(Wall wall : panel.walls) {
            if(hitBox.intersects(wall.hitBox)) {
                hitBox.x -= xspeed;
                while(!wall.hitBox.intersects(hitBox))hitBox.x += Math.signum(xspeed);
                hitBox.x -= Math.signum(xspeed);
                panel.cameraX += x - hitBox.x;
                xspeed = 0;
                hitBox.x = x;
            }

        }
        for(Orange orange : panel.oranges){
            isDed = false;
            if(hitBox.intersects(orange.hitBox)) {
                isDed = false;
                if(panel.orangeCount != 6) {
                    isDed = false;
                keyGlide = false;
                hitBox.x -= xspeed;
                while(!orange.hitBox.intersects(hitBox))hitBox.x += Math.signum(xspeed);
                hitBox.x -= Math.signum(xspeed);
                panel.cameraX += x - hitBox.x;
                xspeed = 0;
                x = hitBox.x;
                panel.orangeCount++;
                panel.reset();
                panel.orangeLabel.setText(": " +(int)panel.orangeCount + "/7");
                onGround = true;
                isDed = false;
                deathSound();
                }
                else {
                    keyGlide = false;
                    hitBox.x -= xspeed;
                    while(!orange.hitBox.intersects(hitBox))hitBox.x += Math.signum(xspeed);
                    hitBox.x -= Math.signum(xspeed);
                    xspeed = 0;
                    x = hitBox.x;
                    onGround = true;
                    panel.orangeCount++;
                    panel.orangeLabel.setText(": " + (int)panel.orangeCount + "/7");
                    orangeSound();
                    System.out.println("Well done");
                    Thread.sleep(1100);
                    System.out.print("your time is ");
                    System.out.println(panel.timeLabel.getText());
                    System.out.println("you died " + (int)deaths + " time(s)");
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            }
        }

        //vertical collision
        hitBox.y += yspeed;
        for(Wall wall : panel.walls) {
            if(hitBox.intersects(wall.hitBox)) {

                keyGlide = false;
                hitBox.y -= yspeed;
                while(!wall.hitBox.intersects(hitBox))hitBox.y += Math.signum(yspeed);
                hitBox.y -= Math.signum(yspeed);
                yspeed = 0;
                y = hitBox.y;
                onGround = true;
            }
        }
        try {
            for(LavaWall lava : panel.lavaWalls) {
                if(hitBox.intersects(lava.hitBox)) {
                    isDed = true;
                    isDeathSound = true;
                    keyGlide = false;
                    hitBox.y -= yspeed;
                    while(!lava.hitBox.intersects(hitBox))hitBox.y += Math.signum(yspeed);
                    hitBox.y -= Math.signum(yspeed);
                    yspeed = 0;
                    y = hitBox.y;
                    onGround = true;
                    isDed = true;
                    die();
                    
                }
            }
        for(Orange orange : panel.oranges){
                isDed = false;
                if(hitBox.intersects(orange.hitBox)) {
                    isDed = false;
                    if(!(panel.orangeCount == 7)) {
                        
                        keyGlide = false;
                        hitBox.y -= yspeed;
                        while(!orange.hitBox.intersects(hitBox))hitBox.y += Math.signum(yspeed);
                        hitBox.y -= Math.signum(yspeed);
                        yspeed = 0;
                        y = hitBox.y;
                        onGround = true;
                        panel.orangeCount++;
                        panel.reset();
                        panel.orangeLabel.setText(": " +(int)panel.orangeCount + "/7");
                        isDed = false;
                        deathSound();
                        
                    }
                    else if(panel.orangeCount == 7) {
                        keyGlide = false;
                        hitBox.y -= yspeed;
                        while(!orange.hitBox.intersects(hitBox))hitBox.y += Math.signum(yspeed);
                        hitBox.y -= Math.signum(yspeed);
                        yspeed = 0;
                        y = hitBox.y;
                        onGround = true;
                        panel.orangeCount++;
                        panel.orangeLabel.setText(": " + (int)panel.orangeCount + "/7");
                        orangeSound();
                        System.out.println("Well done");
                        Thread.sleep(1100);
                        System.out.print("your time is ");
                        System.out.println(panel.timeLabel.getText());
                        System.out.println("you died " + (int)deaths + " time(s)");
                        Thread.sleep(4500);
                        System.out.println("press v to exit");
                    }
                }
            }
        }catch(Throwable e) {

        }
        
        panel.cameraX -= xspeed;
        y += yspeed;
        hitBox.x = x;
        hitBox.y = y;
        //death code
        if(y > 800) {
            isDed = true;
            onGround = true;
            die();
        }enemyScript();
    }void enemyScript() {
        for(Enemy enemy : panel.enemies) {
            if(hitBox.intersects(enemy.hitBox)) {
                isDed = true;
                isDeathSound = true;
                keyGlide = false;
                hitBox.y -= yspeed;
                while(!enemy.hitBox.intersects(hitBox))hitBox.y += Math.signum(yspeed);
                hitBox.y -= Math.signum(yspeed);
                yspeed = 0;
                y = hitBox.y;
                onGround = true;
                isDed = true;
                die();
            }
        }
    }
    void jumpSound(){
        soundEffect("res\\musicAndSoundEffects\\jump.wav");
    }void megaSound(){
        soundEffect("res\\musicAndSoundEffects\\megajump.wav");
    }void glideSound(){
        soundEffect("res\\musicAndSoundEffects\\shorterGlide.wav");
    }void deathSound(){
        if(isDed) {
        soundEffect("res\\musicAndSoundEffects\\death.wav");
        }else if(!isDed) {
            soundEffect("res\\musicAndSoundEffects\\orangeSound.wav");
        }
    }void notDie(){
        stopSound();
    }
    void orangeSound(){
        soundEffect("res\\musicAndSoundEffects\\orangeSound.wav");
    }void stopSound(){
        clip.stop();
    }
    void die() {
        deathSound();
        panel.reset();
        deaths++;
        death.setText("Deaths: " + (int)deaths);
        onGround = true;
    }
    static void soundEffect(String filePath) {
        try {
            File file = new File(filePath);
            AudioInputStream sound = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file);
            clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
            if(onGround && !filePath.equals("res\\musicAndSoundEffects\\shorterGlide.wav")) {
                clip.open(sound);
                clip.setFramePosition(0);
                clip.start();
            }else if(filePath.equals("res\\musicAndSoundEffects\\shorterGlide.wav")) {
                clip.open(sound);
                clip.setFramePosition(0);
                clip.start();
            }

        }catch(Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getStackTrace());
        }
    }
    public void draw(Graphics2D g) {
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
    }
}
```

for anyone who knows the answer to this. Please comment the problem and not the answer so that I can learn. thanks

Answer (score 0):

In broad strokes:

Because you're using a `java.util.Timer` and it is just the wrong tool for the job.

Let's say you want a game to run smoothly, but not slam the CPU of even the most powerful machine imaginable, and also to run as well as it can if the system it runs on is insufficient (that last one is important; even if a system is plenty powerful to run the game, sometimes you get a 'blip' of underperformance because of other stuff the computer was doing, such as when you plug in a USB stick and all sorts of driver shenanigans occurs in the background).

To accomplish these things, you need two crucial properties:

- Timing related to the gameplay (such as, if one of the players is moving northbound, the amount of movement that occurs) should be based entirely on 'time passed', and be unaffected by the amount of time required to actually redraw parts of the screen, nor should it be affected by how many 'loops' of screen refresh you manage to squeeze into a single second.
- Timing related to rendering needs to go fast as possible, but needs a breaking system: BEFORE you begin the task of 'update game state then render the state to the screen', you should calculate the timing at which that should all be done. Then, once you are done with one loop of the game (adjust game state *and* rendering all that), you check whether you 'beat the clock'. If you did, *THEN* wait. In other words, instead of asking a timer to wait a fixed amount of time before doing the next game loop, the amount of time to wait needs to take into account you took some time to adjust the game state and render things.

Here's some example code of a basic game loop. Just use it for inspiration, it doesn't fit verbatim into the code you already have.

```
class Example {
  private static final long NANOS_PER_MILLI =
    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toNanos(1);
  private static final long NANOS_PER_FRAME =
    TimeUnit.SECONDS.toNanos(1) / 60;
  private static final long ADJUST_EXPECTATIONS_TRESHOLD =
    NANOS_PER_FRAME * 5;

  private long start = System.nanoTime();
  private long frameCounter = 0;

  public void run() {
    while (running) {
      gameLoop();
    }
  }

  void gameLoop() {
    frameCounter++;
    long target = startTime + NANOS_PER_FRAME * frameCounter;

    // target now holds the exact time at which point we should
    // be done with this game loop.

    recalcGameState();
    redrawStuff();

    long end = System.nanoTime();
    long delta = target - System.nanoTime();

    if (delta > 0) {
      // We had time to spare!
      // Let's sleep most of that away, giving us
      // a little bit of leeway (5msec worth) in case the system is
      // going to blip on us.

      // Also, CPU waiting is generally granularized at millis,
      // so let's convert to millis first, and be 5 millis 'early'

      long millisToWait = (delta / NANOS_PER_MILLI) - 5;
      if (millisToWait > 0) sleep(millisToWait);
    else if (-delta > READJUST_EXPECTATIONS_TRESHOLD) {
      // Rats - we missed the boat, and by a lot!
      // we are over 5 frames behind, let's readjust
      // expectations and slow down the game logic, too:

        start = end;
        frameCounter = 0;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The above code will reliably render at 60 gameloops every second, (that 5msec leeway will adjust itself on the next loop, as that would just mean you get there even faster and thus wait longer) - and will 'catch up' on a blip for at most 5 frames (catching up a ton of frames after a long blip is usually not a good idea, so we limit the catchup mechanism).

Usually when you're forced into readjustment you may want to adjust the game logic's clocks as well (it is a bit unfair for a player to slam into a wall that was way ahead of them because their CPU just decided to doze off for a second, unlikely as that is, whilst they couldn't steer or even see anything!) - so, have a ball with `gameStart`.

NB: nanoTime is used and not System.currentTimeMillis(), because System.CTM represents the system clock, which means it will drastically change when the user resets their time - modern computers update their clocks by way of a network time server, so this happens all the time (heh), and means that looking at it for frame timing is a bad idea. From time to time the game will do mad glitching when the NTP daemon adjusted the clocks. nanoTime is more or less reflecting 'CPU uptime' and does not get modified when the system clock is adjusted.

NB2: If you need 'frameCounter' to represent game turns, you can't just reset it like this; instead, figure out how many frames you want to adjust by, and then add that many NANOS_PER_FRAME to 'start' instead.